# Issues making a estadistic process in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, struct, while-loop

I'm trying to compile this code in C, its purpose is to accumulate data from a .dat file with structs that have information about marks, age, gender. When I compile it, an error shows that say "segmentation fault", I wrote a printf to show me the value of i, j and k; because I think them are the problem, here is the code and a photo of the failure:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>


struct persona {
    int edad; //EDAD DE 12-65//
    int notas; //NOTAS DE 0-10//
    char sexo; //SEXO 1=MASCULINO Y 2=FEMENINO//
    char exi; //EXI 1=SI 2=NO
};

struct reg {
    int notas;
    int contex;
    int cont;
};

const int imax = 7;
const int jmax = 6;
const int kmax = 3;

struct reg A[imax][jmax][kmax];



void retardo() {
    for(int i=0; i < 11000; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < 11000; j++) {
        }
    }
}
void processbar() {
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    int i, j;
    
    for(i=0; i < 20 ; i++) {
        printf("Cargando... \n");
        printf("====================\n");
        
        for(j=0; j < i ; j++) {
            printf("X");
        }
        printf("\n====================\n");
        retardo();
        system("cls");
    }
}


void etario(int j, char grupoed[10]) //ASIGNAMOS LOS RANGOS ETARIOS//
{
    switch(j)
    {
        case(1):
            grupoed ="12-15";
            break;
        case(2):
            grupoed ="16-25";
            break;
        case(3):
            grupoed ="26-35";
            break;
        case(4):
            grupoed ="36-45";
            break;
        case(5):
            grupoed ="46-55";
            break;
        case(6):
            grupoed = "56-65";
        default:
            printf("\nHa ocurrido un error");
    }
}

void grupoed(struct persona p, int j) {
    if( p.edad < 12) {
        printf("\nexiste un error en la edad");
    }
    if(p.edad < 16) {
        j = 1;
    }
    if(p.edad < 26) {
        j = 2;
    }
    if(p.edad < 36) {
        j = 3;
    }
    if(p.edad < 46) {
        j = 4;
    }
    if(p.edad < 56) {
        j = 5;
    }
    if(p.edad < 66) {
        j = 6;
    }
    else {
        printf("\nexists un error en la edad");
    }
}

void niveling(struct persona p, int i) {
    if(p.notas < 2) {
        i = 1;
    }
    if(p.notas < 4) {
        i = 2;
    }
    if(p.notas < 6) {
        i = 3;
    }
    if(p.notas < 8) {
        i = 4;
    }
    if(p.notas < 10) {
        i = 5;
    }
}

void femasc(struct persona p, int k) {
    if(p.sexo = 'M') {
        k = 1;
    }
    else {
        if(p.sexo = 'F') {
            k = 2;
        }
    }
}

void matrizcero(struct reg A[imax][jmax][kmax], int i, int j, int k) {
    for (i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; i < 6; j++)
        {
            for (k = 1; i < 3; k++)
            {
                A[i][j][k] = {0,0,0};
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    struct reg A[imax][jmax][kmax];
    void processbar();
    void matrizcero(struct reg A[imax][jmax][kmax], int i, int j, int k);
    struct persona p;
    struct reg;
    int i, j, k,rangomay, rangomen, rangointmay, resmay, resmen, jex, jmay, jmen, NIV, GRUPOET, sexo, cantidadM, califM, cantidadF, califF, grupoetario;
    char grupoed[10];
    float prom_m, prom_f;

    FILE *entrada; //ABRO ARCHIVO
    entrada=fopen("datospersonas.dat","rb");
    if (entrada == NULL){
        exit(1);
        printf("\nError al abrir el archivo");
    }
    else {
        printf("\nArchivo abierto exitosamente!");
    }

    while(!(feof(entrada))){
        void niveling(struct persona p, int i);
        void grupoedad(struct persona p, int j);
        void femasc(struct persona p, int k);
    
        printf("\n%d",i);
        printf("\n%d",j);
        printf("\n%d",k);

        A[i][j][k].notas = A[i][j][k].notas + p.notas;
        A[i][j][k].cont = A[i][j][k].cont;
        if(p.exi = 'S') {
            A[i][j][k].contex = A[i][j][k].contex + 1;
        }
        fread(&p,sizeof(p),1,entrada); //LEO ARCHIVO
    }

    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++) { //TOTALIZO HOMBRES Y MUJERES
        for(j = 1; i < 7; i++) {
            A[i][j][3].notas = A[i][j][3].notas + A[i][j][2].notas;
            A[i][j][3].cont = A[i][j][3].cont + A[i][j][2].cont;
            A[i][j][3].contex = A[i][j][3].contex + A[i][j][2].contex;
        }
    }

    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        for(i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            cantidadM = cantidadM + A[i][j][1].cont;
            califM = califM + A[i][j][1].notas;
        }
    }

    prom_m = califM / cantidadM; //PROMEDIO DE CALIFICACIONES DE LOS HOMBRES

    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        for(i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            cantidadF = cantidadF + A[i][j][2].cont;
            califF = califF + A[i][j][2].notas;
        }
    }

    prom_f = califF / cantidadM; //PROMEDIO DE CALIFICACIONES MUJERES

    for(k = 1; k < 3; k++) {
        for(i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
               A[6][j][k].cont = A[6][j][k].cont + A[i][j][k].cont;
               A[6][j][k].contex = A[6][j][k].contex + A[i][j][k].cont;
               A[6][j][k].notas = A[6][j][k].notas + A[i][j][k].notas;
            }
        }
    }

    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        A[6][j][3].cont = A[6][j][1].cont + A[6][j][2].cont;
        A[6][j][3].cont = A[6][j][1].contex + A[6][j][2].contex;
        A[6][j][3].notas = A[6][j][1].notas + A[6][j][2].notas;
    }
    
    resmay = A[6][1][3].contex;
    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        if(A[6][j][3].contex > resmay) {
            resmay = A[6][j][3].contex;
            jex = j;
        }
    }

    for(k = 1; k < 3; k++) {
        for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
            A[7][j][k].notas = A[6][j][k].notas / A[6][j][k].cont;
        }
    }

    resmen = A[7][1][3].notas;
    resmay = A[7][1][3].notas;
    for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
        if(A[7][j][3].notas > resmay) {
            resmay = A[7][j][3].notas;
            jmay = j;
        }
        else {
            if(A[7][j][3].notas < resmen) {
                resmen = A[7][j][3].notas;
                jmen = j;
            }
        }
    }

    void etario(int jmay);
    printf("\nEl rango etario con mayor calificacion en promedio fue el comprendido entre: %s", grupoed, " años");
    void etario(int jmen);
    printf("\nEl rango etario con menor calificacion en promedio fue el comprendido entre: %s", grupoed, " años");
    printf("\nEl promedio de calificaciones en femeninos fue: %f", prom_f);
    printf("\nEl promedio de calificaciones en masculinos fue: %f", prom_m);
    void etario(int jex);
    printf("\nEl rango etario con mayor interes en rendir examenes internacionales es el comprendido entre: %s", grupoed, "años");

    fclose(entrada);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPlEr.jpg)

Just in case, here is the file that generates the .dat file...

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct persona {
    int edad; //EDAD DE 12-65//
    int notas; //NOTAS DE 0-10//
    char sexo; //SEXO 1=MASCULINO Y 2=FEMENINO//
    char exi; //EXI 1=SI 2=NO
};

void generacion()
{
    FILE *entrada;
    entrada=fopen("datospersonas.dat","w+");
    if (entrada == NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(entrada);
}

int main()
{
    int s;
    int exi;
    generacion();
    persona p;
    FILE* entrada;
    entrada=fopen("datospersonas.dat","w+");

        for (size_t i=0;i<30; i++)
        {
            p.edad =(rand() %53)+12;
            p.notas =(rand() %9)+1;
            s=(rand() %2)+1;
            if(s == 1){
                p.sexo='M';
            }
            else{
                p.sexo='F';
            }
            exi=(rand() %2)+1;
            if(exi == 1){
                p.exi='S';
            }
            else{
                p.exi='N';
            }
            fwrite(&p, sizeof(struct persona),1,entrada);
            printf("edad: %d\n",p.edad);
            printf("nota: %d\n",p.notas);
            printf("sexo: %c\n",p.sexo);
            printf("esta interesado en rendir examenes internacionales: %c\n",p.exi);
        }
        fclose(entrada);
        return 0;
}
```

`

I have try writting the print and also process with less structs, I started compiling 500 structs, and now im trying to do it with less than 50...

Comment: How does this comment `char sexo; //SEXO 1=MASCULINO Y 2=FEMENINO//` match this line `p.sexo='M';`? If you use `sexo` as an index, the array must be larger than 3 entries. Also this `if(p.sexo = 'F')` should raise a compiler warning. You need comparison (`==`), not an assignment.

Comment: BTW: Why do you show different code in that picture than you pose here. The faulty place is not present in the code you show here. The lines `k=sexo; A[i][j][k].notes = ...` that cause the crash are not present. Why don't you show the real code?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? `if(p.sexo = 'M') {k = 1;}`? Variable `k` is only a local copy that is not visible to the caller. Check your textbook regarding "call by value" vs call "by reference"

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you very much for helping @Gerhardh . Secondly, i haven't realize this if(p.sexo = 'F' but now i have corrected it, also the line that you show I am not showing are 3 lines that simply assign variables that results from the function to i, j and k; because i think that it's more efficient just asigning directly to i, j and k... But that doesnt solve the problem

Comment: Aside: The `printf` calls in the form `printf("[ ... ]: %s", grupoed, " años")` are not going to do what you want. The third argument is ignored, as there is no associated *format specifier*. Use `printf("[ ... ]: %s%s", grupoed, " años")` or just `printf("[ ... ]: %s años", grupoed)`.

Comment: Aside: Unless you have a purposeful reason to busy-wait, `retardo` can be replaced with a call to [`Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major problems with the code shown:

1. How are functions called?

Functions are called by invoking their name, followed by an argument list.

This

```
fread(&p, sizeof(p), 1, entrada);
```

is an example of the `fread` function being called.

These

```
void processbar();
void matrizcero(struct reg A[imax][jmax][kmax], int i, int j, int k);
```

and these

```
void niveling(struct persona p, int i);
void grupoedad(struct persona p, int j);
void femasc(struct persona p, int k);
```

are examples of [*function declarations*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_declaration). They let the compiler know a function exists, what type of arguments it accepts, and what type of value it returns. Typically you find these at the top of a file (often referred to as *forward declarations*), or in header files (where the function is *defined* in a separate source file). This lets functions relied upon by other functions expose that they exist before they are defined.

For example:

```
/* function declaration */ 
int foo(int);

/* function definition, relies on `foo` */
int bar(void)                                     
{                                                 
    return 4 + foo(1);                            
}                         

/* finally `foo` is defined */
int foo(int a)                      
{                                   
    return a + a;                   
}
```

without the initial declaration of `foo`, `bar` would not know what type of arguments `foo` accepts, and what type of value it returns.

---

2. How to retrieve data from a function.

C is an entirely *pass-by-value* language. This means functions receive *copies* of the values given as arguments. Sometimes functions accept pointers as arguments, but those *pointer values* are still copies. It is the use of indirection with a pointer value that allows C to mimic the *pass-by-reference* behaviour found in other languages.

Function arguments are treated as *local variables* within the function. Changing the value of a function argument does not change the value of any variable in the caller's [*scope*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope). Variables with the same name, but in different scopes, do not refer to the same object.

For example, this program prints `0` and then `1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
                         
void foo(int a) 
{              
    a = 0;     
    printf("%d\n", a);
}                  
                       
int main(void)             
{
    int a = 1;
    foo(a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

If `foo` had changed `a` in the caller's scope, it would print `0` and then `0`, but we see that is not the case.

The main way to *retrieve* data from a function is to use its return value. A function may use the `return` keyword to return a value to its caller.

For example, the `niveling` could be changed to return an `int`:

```
int niveling(struct persona p)          
{                      
    if (p.notas < 2)   
        return 1;  
    if (p.notas < 4)   
        return 2;      
    if (p.notas < 6)         
        return 3;
    if (p.notas < 8)
        return 4;
    if (p.notas < 10)
        return 5;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This function is then used as:

```
struct persona per = { .notas = 7 };
int i = niveling(per);
```

A non-`void` function must always return a value of the appropriate type.

In the case of `etario`, calling it with an array argument is correct, but you must use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) to copy the contents of the string literal into the array.

```
void etario(int j, char grupoed[10])
{
    switch (j) {
        case 1:
            strcpy(grupoed, "12-15")
            break;
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

---

After fixing your program with the above information there are still some critical issues.

Your main loop is malformed, as `fread` is only called at the *end* of the loop, where it should be called towards the start of the loop. You also need to check that the return value of `fread` is equal to the expected number of bytes (`sizeof p`) before trying to use the data read. Failing these two things, `p` is either uninitialized or indeterminate, and using its value is surely to invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior).

See also: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/2505965)

Out of bounds access: if `jmax` is `6`, then the last valid index in the second dimension of your `A` array is `5`.

There are several instances where the array `A` is accessed out of bounds, such as,

```
/* `j` reaches `6`, an invalid index */
for(j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        cantidadM = cantidadM + A[i][j][1].cont;
```

and where you have used `i` instead of `j`, or some similar typographic error:

```
for (i = 1; i < 7; i++) {
    /* `i` is used in the condition of the inner loop  */
    for (j = 1; i < 6; j++)
```

If you create "constants" like `imax`, `jmax`, and `kmax`, then you should use them throughout your code instead of using magic numbers everywhere. Constants are conventionally uppercase as well.

Example:

```
const int IMAX = 7;
const int JMAX = 6;

/* ... */

for (int i = 0; i < IMAX; i++)          
    for (int j = 0; j < JMAX; j++)
        /* ... */
```

You also have syntax issues such as:

```
if (p.sexo = 'M')
```

`=` is the assignment operator. `==` is the equality operator.

---

Conclusion: A good compiler with a competent warning level would help you greatly, so you should turn your compiler warnings way up. With MSVC, use at least `/W4` or `/Wall`, and possibly `/Wx` to enforce better coding practices. See: [Warning levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170).

You also need to study the language more closely. Consider picking up a good [C textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/2505965).

Comment: Hi, I've been trying that suggestions that you said to me, now mi biggest problem is that the value of i, j, k are broken; i don't know why but them take values that are not define at the functions. Also thank you very mucho for helping me...

Comment: My code its like this right now´´